# Generate m outcomes of a geometric random variable using the cdf of the random variable

Tags: matlab, octave, probability, cdf, bernoulli-probability

As part of an assignment, I have been asked to write an Octave function that will generate *m* pseudorandom outcomes of a geometric RV *X* with parameter *p = 0.55* in 2 separate ways:

1. Directly using the cdf of the RV
2. Using the fact that the variable is produced using independent Bernoulli experiments.

For 2, my thoughts are:

- create a loop of *m* iterations
- create an inner loop that repeats until there is a successful trial
- have a counting variable in the inner loop that counts how many failures there are before a success, and store this count for each of the *m* iterations of the outer loop.

However, I am quite lost with part one, and am struggling to even understand what the question means by "directly using the cdf of the random variable".

**EDIT**

Here is what I have done so far:

```
function x = generate_geometric_cdf(p, m)
  % generate geometric RV X with parameter p, m times using the cdf

  emperical = zeros(1,m);         % allocate array for empirical results of m simulations
  for i = 1:m                     % iterate over m simulations
    u = rand;                     % generate a random number between 0-1
    emperical(i) = geocdf(u, p);  % store the outcome of the geometric distribution at u           
  end

end
```

**EDIT 2**

`geoinv` was the function I needed as opposed to `geocdf`. `geocdf(u, p)` returns the probability from the cdf for of value `u`, with parameter `p` whereas `geoinv(u, p)` does the inverse and returns a random value given the probability `u` and parameter `p`.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @NKN no problem, see my edit.

Comment: You would need a `while` loop, not a `for`, because the required number of operations is unknown beforehand. Also, within the loop you would generate a Bernoulli random variable, say `b = rand<p;`,  and use that as loop condition. That uses Bernoulli random variables, but not "the CDF" of the geometric variable

Comment: @LuisMendo I have done exactly that for part 2 of the question, it is part 1 I am trying to figure out.